# Apache and nginx running together on VPS?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx

I have a VPS with a number of PHP sites that are hosted with Apache.
I am looking to launch my first Python site quite soon and - as advised in the documentation - would like to use a separate web server to host static content.

I don't really want to mess around with my existing sites and risk causing them to be down for any period of time, however I do have a secondary IP address which, so far I have not used.

Would it be possible to make nginx listen to this secondary address and then simply serve the static content via a subdomain (static.mydomain.com) through nginx?

Are there any complications I would be likely to encounter with this method or is it considered bad practice in any way?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to bind nginx to different IP by using [listen](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#listen) directive. It is good practice to use nginx as server for static content or as http accelerator for apache server.